# Laravel how to stop a scheduled task in php code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have several scheduled tasks runs in background mode using Laravel scheduler, I want to use php code to control which one to start and which one to stop, I know how to start a scheduled task, but how to stop a scheduled task in PHP code?

I don't see it in the Laravel scheduler doc.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check the help section (stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on how to improve your question (for example showing us what you have attempted so far).

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create a flag somewhere (Model, Cache) and check it when the task gets processed.

The queue in Laravel is just that, a queue. It is not meant to hold state or other information.

Comment: yes I know that, but anyway to stop a specific task programatically ?

Comment: You can't really, check in the task if it should run or not.